# Unable to change binding after hard binding function using 'bind'

Tags: javascript

I just came up with the following snippet while trying to understand binding functions.

```js
var obj = {
  a: function test() {
    console.log(this.b);
  }.bind(window),
  b: 'b object value'
};

window.b = 'b window value';
```

Now, if I execute the following:

```js
var fn = obj.a.bind(obj);

fn(); // Prints 'b window value'
```

Even after hard binding again to `obj`, `b window value` is printed. How can I modify the above code so that `obj.a` function prints `b object value`?

I am hoping to achieve this without modifying the first block of code.

Comment: You can't.  That's sort of the whole point of `bind`.

Comment: @JamesThorpe So there's no way to unbind once a function is bound to an object?